# How do I run a JS program inside node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, netbeans

I have been programming for a long time using Khan Academy, but now I want to execute the code from my khanacademy program inside netbeans. I downloaded and installed `node.js` and copied my code into a JavaScript file, but when I try to run it, I get this:

> /bin/sh: line 1: node: command not found

I thought it might be because I don't have my code inside a frame, but I can't figure out how to add one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your PATH does not include the location of the node executable.
As you are using OSX, execute the following command in the Terminal:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have node in your path. You can test that by running

```
which node
```

If this command doesn't return anything, you need to add node to your path.

```
export PATH=$PATH;/path/to/node
```

Edit: Commands assuming Linux/OSX, problem would be the same in Windows but commands would be different.

Comment: Where do I put that code? I tried putting it in my js file and got an error message.

Comment: I tried adding node to my path and couldn't. Any suggestions?

Comment: Run that on the command line, not in your js.